# Call a local variable in doInbackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i m using an asynctask but i  can't handle local variables in doInBackground method so in my case when i want to set the local variable test i got an error 
so what can i do ? 
and when i set test with this way test="testme" without this i didn't got an error but test is always null.
so what can i do to set a local variable in doinbackground method

```
public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask{
    Context context;
    User user2 ;
    String test;
    private User authentifcatedUser;

    public ConnectTask(User authentifcatedUser) {
        this.authentifcatedUser = authentifcatedUser;

    }

    public User getAuthentifcatedUser() {
        return authentifcatedUser;
    }

    public void setAuthentifcatedUser(User authentifcatedUser) {
        this.authentifcatedUser = authentifcatedUser;
    }



    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public  User getUser(){
        return  this.user2;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        connect();

        return test;
    }

    public String connect(){


        final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/users");
                Query query = ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo("testme");
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                          User  user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                           System.out.println("my birth day is "+user.getDateOfBirth());

                          user2=new User(user.getUsername(),user.getEmail(),user.getPassword(),user.getSignUpDate(),user.dateOfBirth);
                            System.out.println("my email is" + user2.getEmail());
                            test="aaaaaaaaa";


                        }

                       /* User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        Log.w( "tag", dataSnapshot.toString());*/

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                    }

                });


        return test;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);

        System.out.println("retuuuurn"+connect())   ;

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want?? are you trying to say `test="aaaaaaaaa";` is not going to set the value of `test`??

Comment: yes i want to set the test value

Comment: refer to @Sohail Zahid's answer below.. it is correct

Comment: it dosen't work :/

Comment: how you came to know it is not working how you are printing the value of test?? or where you are using that??

Comment: can not resolve method error

Comment: write context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
          public void run() {
          //btn.setText("#" + i);
          test ="???";
          }
      });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Asynctask doInBackground()` methods works in background thread you cant manipulate UI Thread objects in background thread thats why you are getting problem.

To make changes in background thread you can by using below code in `doInBackground()`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
          public void run() {
          //btn.setText("#" + i);
          test ="???";
          }
      });
```

Update in Your Case

```
 public String connect() {

        final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/users");
        Query query = ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo("testme");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    System.out.println("my birth day is " + user.getDateOfBirth());

                    user2 = new User(user.getUsername(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.getSignUpDate(), user.dateOfBirth);
                    System.out.println("my email is" + user2.getEmail());
//                    test = "aaaaaaaaa";
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() { 
                            test = "aaaaaaaaa";
                        }
                    });

                       /* User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        Log.w( "tag", dataSnapshot.toString());*/
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
        return test;
    }
```

Comment: but it dosen't work when i call it in doInBackground

Comment: protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        connect();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //btn.setText("#" + i);
                test ="???";
            }
        });

        return test;
    }

Comment: resolved : i used  runOnUiThread and by the way runOnUiThread is method of android.app.Activity so i passed the activity in the constructor of my task

Comment: @fatma19 if my answer helps you any way please consider tick and vote up.